# How to fix a Memory Map Failed Exception for GPIO write on raspberry pi

Tags: c#, monodevelop, raspberry-pi2, gpio

I'm trying to use the Raspberry Sharp IO library to write to a pin on the Pi. But it gives me an exception on runtime. It had worked before, but doesnt any more. Why is this error being thrown?

```
using System;
using Raspberry.IO.GeneralPurpose;
using Raspberry.IO.GeneralPurpose.Behaviors;
using System.Threading;

  namespace blinky
    {
       class MainClass
     {
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {

    // Here we create a variable to address a specific pin for output
    // There are two different ways of numbering pins--the physical numbering, and the CPU number
    // "P1Pinxx" refers to the physical numbering, and ranges from P1Pin01-P1Pin40
        var led1 = ConnectorPin.P1Pin03.Output();

    // Here we create a connection to the pin we instantiated above
    var connection = new GpioConnection(led1);

    while(true){
        // Toggle() switches the high/low (on/off) status of the pin
        connection.Toggle(led1);
        Thread.Sleep(250);
    }

//  connection.Close();

}
}
 }
```

returns this error:

```
pi@Minion01 ~/blinky1/blinky1/bin/Debug $ mono ./blinky1.exe

Unhandled Exception:
Raspberry.IO.Interop.MemoryMapFailedException: Exception of type 'Raspberry.IO.Interop.MemoryMapFailedException' was thrown.
  at Raspberry.IO.Interop.MemoryMap.ThrowOnError[MemoryMapFailedException] (IntPtr result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Raspberry.IO.Interop.MemoryMap.Create (IntPtr address, UInt32 size, MemoryProtection protection, MemoryFlags memoryflags, Int32 fileDescriptor, UInt32 offset) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Raspberry.IO.GeneralPurpose.GpioConnectionDriver..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Raspberry.IO.GeneralPurpose.GpioConnectionSettings.GetBestDriver (GpioConnectionDriverCapabilities capabilities) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Raspberry.IO.GeneralPurpose.GpioConnectionSettings.get_DefaultDriver () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Raspberry.IO.GeneralPurpose.GpioConnectionSettings..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Raspberry.IO.GeneralPurpose.GpioConnection..ctor (Raspberry.IO.GeneralPurpose.GpioConnectionSettings settings, IEnumerable`1 pins) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Raspberry.IO.GeneralPurpose.GpioConnection..ctor (Raspberry.IO.GeneralPurpose.PinConfiguration[] pins) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at blinky.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Raspberry.IO.Interop.MemoryMapFailedException: Exception of type 'Raspberry.IO.Interop.MemoryMapFailedException' was thrown.
  at Raspberry.IO.Interop.MemoryMap.ThrowOnError[MemoryMapFailedException] (IntPtr result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Raspberry.IO.Interop.MemoryMap.Create (IntPtr address, UInt32 size, MemoryProtection protection, MemoryFlags memoryflags, Int32 fileDescriptor, UInt32 offset) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Raspberry.IO.GeneralPurpose.GpioConnectionDriver..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Raspberry.IO.GeneralPurpose.GpioConnectionSettings.GetBestDriver (GpioConnectionDriverCapabilities capabilities) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Raspberry.IO.GeneralPurpose.GpioConnectionSettings.get_DefaultDriver () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Raspberry.IO.GeneralPurpose.GpioConnectionSettings..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Raspberry.IO.GeneralPurpose.GpioConnection..ctor (Raspberry.IO.GeneralPurpose.GpioConnectionSettings settings, IEnumerable`1 pins) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Raspberry.IO.GeneralPurpose.GpioConnection..ctor (Raspberry.IO.GeneralPurpose.PinConfiguration[] pins) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at blinky.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

How may i fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had tried to run this through monodevelop on the pi and also using `mono filename.exe` . Neither worked. But it did when I used `sudo ./filename.exe`.

Comment: Also, `sudo mono filename.exe` does the same thing and works (in case anyone gets confused).